# magento disable proceed to checkout until condition is true

Tags: magento

What magento method I can use to stop the checkout button to function until a certain condition its true?
basically is a user has deleted a product on basket while he must not checkout until two products are on the basket

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    parent::deleteAction();

   if($this->_getCart()->getQuote()->getItemsCount() == 1) {
      $this->addErrorMessage('Please remove one voucher. Or add one More infant milk product');
    }
    }
```

Comment: I see "vouchers": did you set a coupon, and you need the customers to have more than one item to use it? In this case you'll find an useful condition from the admin panel -> cart rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite easy to accomplish using the config flag `checkout/options/onepage_checkout_enabled`:

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    parent::deleteAction();

   if($this->_getCart()->getQuote()->getItemsCount() == 1) {

       Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig('checkout/options/onepage_checkout_enabled',0);
   }

}
```

**A side note:**

It's not really necessary to rewrite the controller here, as you could handle it in a postdispatch controller observer action:

```
<events>
    <controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_delete>
        <observers>
            <yourmodule_postdispatch_delete>
                <class>yourmodel/observer</class>
                <method>deletePostdispatch</method>
            </yourmodule_postdispatch_delete>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_delete>
</events>
```

And the observer method would look like:

```
public function deletePostdispatch($observer)
{
   if(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCount()==1){

       Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig('checkout/options/onepage_checkout_enabled',0);
   }

}
```

HTH, Cheers!

Comment: Insanely awful solutions `Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig('checkout/options/onepage_checkout_enabled',0)` will disable checkout for all users on that store not only the current one.

Comment: Incorrect. This setting will only persist in the user session unless you call save on the object. If you call save, then yes, it is I'll advised.

Comment: Nice. Was not aware of that.

Comment: User can still open checkout page by typing url in browser. It only hides "Proceed to Checkout" button.

Comment: This is a suitable solution for most end-users.