# magento doesn't respond on an if statement

Tags: magento

To stop the checkout button to function until a certain condition its true? basically if a user has added two products on cart he is allowed to add two vouchers, and i've done that part but when a product that was added on basket has been removed by the user the voucher still exist on cart here is my code that suppose to remove the voucher but doesn't work;

```
public function deleteAction()
{

    parent::deleteAction();
    $vouchers = Mage::getResourceModel('healthystart/voucher_collection');
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems('name');

    foreach($vouchers as $voucher){
        if  ($voucher['quote_id'] > 1 && $items['quote_id'] === 1){
            echo "hi"; exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Posting the contents of your ResourceModel would help. Also be aware of CollectTotals http://www.classyllama.com/blog/unravelling-magentos-collecttotals-core-process

Comment: possible duplicate of [magento disable proceed to checkout until condition is true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339088/magento-disable-proceed-to-checkout-until-condition-is-true)